# How to refer to "True-like" and "False-like" when documenting a function?

Tags: python, code-documentation

[Strongly related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372312/how-to-describe-function-arguments-in-dynamic-typed-languages).

When writing docstrings for my functions in python, I sometimes want to write something like this about argument specifications:

```
def foo(bar):
    """
    Do some stuff.

    bar : callable
        must return True if XXX and False otherwise.
    """

    if bar(...):
        ...  # code goes here
```

However, this is not perfectly precise, because in this example `bar` could be returning any object that will be evaluated to `True` in the if-statement when the conditions XXX is fulfilled. Such a callable would be a perfectly valid argument to pass to `foo`.

**How should I formulate my documentation to reflect that `foo` does not strictly requires `bar`'s output to be a boolean?**

My first move was to write something like "[...] must return an object that will be evaluated to True if ...", but I find it obfuscated.

Comment: A common way to refer to this is _truthy_ and _falsey_.  However, this is really no requirement at all, because _any_ value returned by `bar()` will be either truthy or falsey.

Comment: How objects evaluate to true or false is often called "truthiness". Also, [falsey is often spelled falsy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/109996/is-it-falsy-or-falsey).

Comment: @JohnGordon there are exceptions like numpy arrays. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862526/can-the-python-bool-function-raise-an-exception-for-an-invalid-argument) for further context.

Comment: @timgeb Fair enough.

Comment: Another (strange) case would be if foo makes assumptions about bar returning only bools, by computing x = 5 * bar(...), to obtain 5 or 0. Then bar could return a truthy or falsy but create unexpected behavior.

Comment: You can say `bool(bar())` must evaluate to `True` or `False`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a slang question! I've always wanted to answer one of these!

Ahem.

---

The term for something that evaluates to `True` when used in an `if` statement is "truthy". The term for something that evaluates to `False` when used in an `if` statement is "falsy" or "falsey". So, your documentation can be written like this:

```
def foo(bar):
    """
    Do some stuff.

    bar : callable
        must return a truthy value iff XXX.
    """

    if bar(...):
        ...  # code goes here
```

"Iff" is more slang, this time from the mathematical world. It means "if and only if". These words are commonly used in programming contexts, so I expect most programmers will understand them; if not, [truthy](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=truthy+meaning), [falsy](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=falsy+meaning), [falsey](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=falsey+meaning) and [iff](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=iff+meaning) all come up with their respective correct meanings when searched in a search engine.

Comment: @John Gordon: I did see your comment but I am glad to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a standard for this, but based on python's [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) you would probably be safe writing something like

```
def foo(bar):
    """
    Do some stuff.

    bar : callable
        when tested for truth value, return value should evaluate to True if and only if XXX.
    """

    if bar(...):
        ...  # code goes here
```

Comment: Verbose, but safe. Good in some contexts.

Comment: "evaluates to True (False)" would be also my anwer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that is is just fine to say "must return True if XXX and False otherwise." Because of duck typing, I read this the way you intend. Further, this seems to be standard in how the Python standard library documents things.

In fact, if you *do* strictly require the value to be `True` or `False` and use this language, I will have a very bad day tracking down this bug!

As others have said, "truthy" and "falsy" are fine, well-understood alternatives if you are still concerned.